# escape BQ keywords based column spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks

Here is the scenario:

I have a table in Bigquery which has a column named range. Now, I have a spark-scala job that reads data from this table. It also has certain complex transforms involved. Now, the job fails stating the reason that
INVALID_ARGUMENT: request failed: Row filter for  is invalid. Filter is '(range IS NOT NULL)' ...
This is a filter that it automatically generates.
Also, I dont have the liberty to use custom sql to read data. It has to be worked on via tempview mechanism that too developed over table read via spark bigquery library.

Is there any way in which we can force spark to use backticks like "`range`" in its SQL that it generates? Or is there a workaround for this issue?

I cannot provide the code details here as I am not allowed to due to the nature of the project. But, if need be I can try to provide details if needed.

Any leads would be helpful.

Comment: Can you clarify if just reading the table, with no transformations, and .show works?  ie. is it the transformations or the bigquery connector that is the issue.

Comment: Direct reading the table works. If I list the columns of the loaded dataframe, it shows the column correctly. But, as soon as, I add any joins/ filters, the above issue pops up. My understanding is that the dialect for BQ in spark is the actual source of the issue. Even if I set the dialect (spark.sql.dialect) to BQ, it is still the same.

Comment: so you are able to add filters then just not to the original query, does manually adding backticks to \`range\` is not null not work?

Comment: I am not manually using range is not null, That is the place where everything starts to mess up. There are join wherein that column is being used. Now, if I had the choice to use custom sql, then my problem would have been solved. But its the automatic query that spark generates that is causing all the trouble.

Comment: sorry to keep asking but are you able to show and control the join?  Clearly if you can't change the code then you can't fix it by adding backticks and as there is not even information about the stack trace or if the error is from Spark or Bigquery it's really difficult to try and help further